# Create opening and closing html tags around an existing html structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create opening and closing html tags around an existing html structure with JavaScript or jQuery.

The html structure looks like this:

```
<div class="coursePrerequisites">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum..
    </p>
</div>
```

I would like to wrap the p tag inside a div with the class *.description-wrapper* dynamically.

How can I do that with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function to do that.

```
$( ".coursePrerequisites p" ).wrap("<div class='description-wrapper'></div>");
```

Comment: Oh .. I did not know the wrap function of jquery yet. This will of course make it easier: D. Thank you!